# How important are Korean idioms and phrases for TOPIK exam?

Tags: vocabulary, topik

I have been going through Korean idioms and phrases. Are idioms useful for topik exam?

Comment: Which level TOPIK are you preparing for?

Comment: I guess studying common Korean sentence patterns(문형) might help more. These start from primitive patterns like `~는 ~이다` to advanced patterns like `홧김에 ~하다(해 버리다)` or `~할 수밖에 없다`. Being used to the patterns in both reading/listening and writing/speaking, one will definitely enhance their language skills in a comprehensive way. Idioms are just very special language patterns used in very specific situations, and they are especially hard to be get used to. Actually, using idioms or phrases at an inappropriate situation may even make a writing or speech worse than not using it.

Comment: I think this type of question would be more appropriate for chat.

Answer (score 2):

http://m.topik.go.kr/m/cmm/subLocation.do?menuSeq=212010102

You should probably not study too hard about phrases.
Phrases are only like grammar + words, so I don't recommend studying phrases
and I recommend practicing writing, you can earn many points in questions about that.

Comment: that being said I think there is at least one reading passage where you need to decipher an idiom, a phrasal verb or other similar literary construct. I don't think they are as pervasive in the listening section. For the writing section, I have been told that if you haven't really grasped the meaning of a proverb or idiom, it's better not to use that in your composition to make it look more advanced, as using an idiom out of context will likely result in more negative marks.